How might communications on Mars work between bases if humans were there?
How might communications on Mars work between bases if humans were there? For example if there were humans on bases at the equator and the poles, would real time communication be possible? What infrastructure would need to be set up? How might existing infrastructure be used? I'm thinking very early settlers, and would like a very "hard sci-fi" approach to this rather than imagining cellphone towers magically appearing.

Hello @blargtronic, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Did you read the [tag:hard-science] wiki? Answers that don't meet its expectations are under threat of deletion. Respondents are required to prove their answer is correct through mathematics and/or citations. It doesn't refer to the hard scifi book genre. Sure you need it and not [tag:science-based]?

You just need to replicate Starlink on mars.  We are pretty close to being able to do that now.

When asking for "hard science", please define "real time communication".

"Real time" only means that there is a timing requirement. It doesn't tell us anything about the time scale. E.g., is it acceptable if you can send a message and receive a reply within one second? Or, do you need to receive the reply within one millisecond? Those both could be called "real-time requirements" even though there's a world of difference between them.

Satellite radio.
I'm sitting at the equator. You are sitting at some point in the arctic on the same hemisphere of the planet as me. I want to show you my cool new rock, so I call you up on a high-def video call. My space phone talks to its radio. Its radio talks to my digital repeater. My repeater has a dish antenna, which is pointed somewhere on the arc from east to west. My repeater talks to the long-term satellite we left in orbit at that point, which picks it up with an equator-facing antenna and repeats the signal through its pole-facing antenna to talk to your repeater.
Your repeater picks up the signal through its just-over-the-horizon-facing antenna. Your repeater talks to your space phone's radio. Your space phone's radio talks to your space phone, which displays my video of my cool new space rock.
If you're on the opposite hemisphere (or over the horizon as viewed from the satellite, if it's close enough to not view a full hemisphere), we probably need at least one more repeater satellite, otherwise we won't be able to send real-time high def video of our cool rocks, which will be bad for morale.
We already got here on space ships with parts (like their big solar arrays and dish antennas) that weren't designed to land. Leaving them in permanent orbits is close to free.

I was just about to click "submit" when your post arrived. Five satellites cover 100% of the surface of the planet. One over each pole and three orbiting at equidistant points around the equator. And since we have the tech to set up bases on Mars, we obviously have the tech for satellites. +1.

@JBH: It's more than five, because satellites cannot really hover over the poles, but still it's only a quite small number of satellites.

Likewise, this answer covers everything I was going to say having read the question.  It would be irresponsible not to have comms coverage by satellite well before we put anyone on the surface.

@AlexP You can actually get full coverage with four. Think of it as nearly-equatorial orbits, but slightly tipped so each sat covers the north pole almost half the time and the south pole almost half the time. It's known as a Draim constellation or Draim tetrahedron after it's inventor/discoverer.

Real life Mars spacecraft commonly use in-orbit spacecraft to communicate with Earth. For example, Curiosity and Perserverance use MRO and Odessey to communicate with Earth, and the Chinese rover, I believe, used its orbiter too. This is because it is incredibly more energy and time-efficient to just send your data to a closer object with a bigger antenna. there are other reasons too, this is just how I interpret it.

There are already five orbiting satellites in the Mars Relay Network. You would probably have a laser link to Earth, as demonstrated recently on Psyche with cloud storage, with an increasing number of relay satellites as demand expands. The relay satellites could be made on Earth, and would be cheap as they don't have to land on Mars, which is the tricky bit.
The alternative would be to lay cables. Most of the surface of Mars is empty, so you could just lay them on the surface, with solar power from the relay amplifiers. But this would mean having tens of thousands of kilometres of fibre. Optical fibre weighs between 10 and 600 g/m depending a lot on the strength of the sheath, and you may want to be on the upper end of this if your cable is on the surface and going to be driven over. If we guess at 100 g/m, a link going around the equator would weigh 1000 tons. That would cost a lot to ship from Earth, and you would need substantial technology to make it on Mars. A fibre network might come much later when you have cities rather than bases.

Mars has lots of (impure) silica at the surface; you could ship a fiber "factory" for less mass than an equatorial single-strand fiber and, over a course of years, make all the fiber you could possibly want.

You could do that. You could even have a laser connection direct to Mars. However, laser to satellite with the current Mars Relay system would give a pretty good coverage, though you might have to wait for a satellite to be well above the horizon, but that would be good enough to start with.  Something like 81 Starlink satellites would give complete coverage from equator to poles.

The problem with fiber is that it's subject to radiation damage. Further, a fiber optic network isn't just fiber. You need a amplifier every ~150 km. The EDFAs, pump lasers and photodiodes are particularly susceptible to radiation damage. Not only that, they need power. Under the sea, you run high voltage over Cu or Al to power the amps: that is likely going to dominate your mass and material budget.

Solar power might not be the best choice for remote generation on Mars. Dust storms would mean the panels would need frequent cleaning and you'd need twice as many panels as on earth because you're only getting 43% of the energy from the sun. Probably better to do what we do under the sea, what @user71659 suggested.

On Earth the ionosphere helps radio communication by bouncing off radio waves and allowing direct communications between stations located below the horizon with respect to each other, as was demonstrated by Marconi sending a signal between Cornwall and Newfoundland in 1901.
Mars has a ionosphere too, so it's realistic to assume that the same effect on radio communication will happen.
As long as the communication happens on the right frequency, direct communication will be possible.

Anyway, long waves are not dependent on ionosphere, using them for communication should be available. However long waves do not allow a lot of bandwidth, so it'll be probably a single broadcast channel for everyone, hmmm.

Voice-only or low-rate data can be sent on fairly narrow channels; assuming long wave refers to what we'd call that, there's room for dozens of simplex voice or low data rate channels in that band (you don't have a population of billions, a tiny microfraction of whom might want to use that band).  If all your radios are frquency-agile, it might well seem to users that they have the band to themselves.

HF communication on Mars has been modeled (pg 14). It works but far less than on Earth. The ionosphere of Mars is an order of magnitude less charged due to lower solar flux and the lack of significant magnetic field allowing solar wind to have a much greater effect.

I know people who had internet access based on HF radio in the 90s, so it's definitely possible.

There was an experiment to create an artificial ionosphere. While successful, it turned out to be a very unpopular source of space debris: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_West_Ford

The question asks for high-bandwidth connections, ionosphere-reflected RF not offer than, so that answer won't work. It could still be used as a backup, of course.

Ionospheric bounce propagation on Earth does work but isn't your trusty fiber link!  Just to create one point of perspective.  It depends on the ionization level, the radio frequency, the level of ionization and the angle of incidence on the ionosphere.  So, some frequencies work in the day and others better at night.  Sun spot cycles affect the ionization so there's a 10 year cycle of good and not-so-good.
Bringing Mars into the discussion brings a whole level of negatives relative to Earth.  There is one ionospheric layer on Mars compared to a handful on Earth.  So, less opportunity to use what's there.  The geometry of Mars (being about half the size of Earth) means that angles of incidence of radio waves on its ionosphere are higher and less likely to be reflective for a given frequency.  And, the distance to the horizon affects the ability to hit at lower grazing angles which are often helpful.  The aspect of multiple-hop paths compared to Earth is also detrimental.
So, don't count on ionospheric propagation on Mars to be very likely.  Possible in some limited circumstances - yes.  Likely to be mechanized, probably not?
user71659 references a good paper that suggests how it can work.  Perhaps that's good enough for it to be likely.

The major issues with Mars's ionosphere is that solar flux is lower, due to its distance, and Mars doesn't have a significant magnetic field like the Earth that shields the ionosphere from solar wind. Nonetheless, HF propagation is modeled to be possible (pg 14)..

It depends a bit on how early your settlements will be.
In my opinion early settlers probably won't care much about a convenient quick responding communication across the planet.
The missing oxygen and the cold temperatures on Mars make it a very deadly environment.
Sure you can make pressurized buildings but if anything goes wrong you want to have a backup plan and a backup for the backup.
The focus is probably more on the survival than on setting up a few convenient research stations across the entire planet.
As early settler I would set up my station relatively near to others so that I can reach them by rover within a few hours.
Within such small distances you can easily set up one small radio tower per station and use your mobile phone to chat with your neighbours.
A temporary trip to the poles might be more feasible than a permanent and far away station.
Sure, you may have several settling spots among the planet where quick communication across is not possible, but it is probably better to spend the money and effort into your local infrastructure than in an expensive remote communication network.
First get your hightec 3D-printer going, then you can use it to build a factory to make fiber cables.
We already have 3D-printers which can print concrete or metal, so a hightec 3D-printer to build up settlements is quite realistic to achieve.
If you like to, you could use a container full of plastic granules and a few bags of microchips and micro antennas to spam the planet with cheap cellphone towers.
Maybe not. It might be difficult to power them and the communication delay among multiple relay points is probably longer than via satelite.

On Earth there's life everywhere, and active weather systems. This means that we have to protect cables, to avoid destruction by human, animal, geological or meteorological activity.
Mars has a little bit of weather, but no flash floods, no animals biting the cable - and not much human activity, even with a few bases here and there.

Launching satellites is expensive. 

Satellites require infrastructure, that you don't require with fiber optics. They use more power, as you don't carefully direct your signal.
Simply roll out fiber optic cable and bury it under a few centimeters of sediment. It's a cheap and well tested technology - and the cables and required amplifiers are resilient enough that we lower them into thousands of meters of conductive salt water (the amplifiers use electricity) at earth.
This will have higher capacity and lower latency than satellite radio communication. The communication infrastructure will be more resilient and reliable than radio signals.

But to get to mars in the first place you need to orbit; its actually more expensive to land than to put satellites in orbit.

@Seggan true, that point is somewhat moot. Rest still stands.

The latency stands.  The capacity, maybe not; unless you have a manufacturing base on Mars to make all the necessary components, it's going to be cheaper to leave a small flotilla of satellites in orbit than to transport and land the necessary infrastructure to build a fibre optic network.

@Seggan more expensive but the first solar flare can't take out a fiber cables, without a magnetosphere satellites are not that reliable

@John i wasnt arguing that; my point was that satellites are actually the cheapest way to get this done, contrary tot he answer's claim

@John Without a magnetosphere, fiber cables are not that reliable. Radiation damages glass, which is a major issue today for space applications of fiber amplifiers and why satellites use spinning gyroscopes long after the rest of the world went to fiber optic gyros.

Satellite infrastructure is sent there with your original rockets: You just leave it in orbit, and you can connect to any base in its targeting-arc — setup is near-instant. Fibre has to be laid down along the entire route between bases (although, you can run one central "hub" base, and the others on "spokes") which is a lot more infrastructure and takes longer. Fibre needs (lots of) repeaters, which adds to the infrastructure, but also need power. Satellites are unaffected by marsquakes. More parts to go wrong means less resilient and less reliable. This answer is almost entirely backwards

Look at Starlink: the only infrastructure you need is a relativity compact antenna to send and receive the signal.
